# event handlers in vb

Tags: vb.net, events

I am having some shorthand problems in vb events. It is having recognizing the me.event As per Hans's suggestion I have dumped the checking if empty for just running the event. I have tried to turn the short hand into long hand with the help of .net knowledge base, but I am just so lost. Please help.

```
Private Sub OnRegister_ServerOperationCompleted(ByVal arg As Object)
        Dim args As InvokeCompletedEventArgs = DirectCast(arg, InvokeCompletedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Me.Register_ServerCompleted.Invoke(Me, New Register_ServerCompletedEventArgs(args.Results, args.Error, args.Cancelled, args.UserState))
    End Sub'
```

Comment: I am getting event can not be called directly when checking if it is empty and if will not allow use of the namespace me in the raise event.

Comment: It is not valid VB.NET code and there is no way to check if the event is "empty".  It is not C#.  When it has no subscribers then RaiseEvent just doesn't do anything so you don't have to help.  If it is important to help then you must create a Custom event so you can count the number of AddHandler and RemoveHandler calls.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error with some help. This was supposed to make another instance of the class invokecompletedeventsargs, not raise that event. I removed the Event and replaced it as a private. It is now functioning. Thank  you for all your suggestions.